# Regular expression arraylist

Tags: java, android, regex, csv, arraylist

I am using an arraylist to store float values that I write onto a txt file as csv(comma separated values). I have ran into a problem with my non North American users that use the decimal mark comma "," instead of a period "."

Here is the output of one of my files using German locale:

```
 ,0,003, 0,06, 0,22, 1,01
, 0,015, 0,06, 0,21, 1,02
```

Here is the American version that works fine as a csv file:

```
 ,0.007, -0.05, 0.75, 0.72
, 0.014, -0.04, 0.76, 0.71
```

How can I have the German version fixed? I need to replace ONLY the comma that separates each value set with a semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work now.

Assumptions:

- All numbers contain a comma

RegEx:

```
(\d+),(\d+)
```

Replace:

```
$1.$2
```

Java:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class JavaRegEx2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line = ", 0,003, 0,06, 0,22, 1,01 , -0,015, 0,06, 0,21, 1,02";
    String pattern = "(\\d+),(\\d+)";

    String updated = line.replaceAll(pattern, "$1.$2"); 

    System.out.println(updated);

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following pattern [*(example online)*](http://regex101.com/r/lR2hU8) match with the decimals comma.

```
(?<=[\d]),(?=[\d]+(?:,|$|\s))
```

Then you replace it with a period.

*java code example:*

```
System.out.println("0,003, 0,06, 0,22, 1,01 , 0,015, 0,06, 0,21, 1,02".replaceAll("(?<=[\\d]),(?=[\\d]+(?:,|$|\\s))", "."));
```

Comment: There is an invalid escape sequence on the code. Thanks for the help. Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: yes, I was such a hurry that left some mistakes, so sorry. But I hope it helped {: